# IIS Router Site rewrite rule doesn't find resource file when accessed with resource /current

Tags: iis

On my IIS I have configured rewrite rules in the following way.
There is a Router Site which listens on port 80 and rewrites to proper websites by specified resource e.g when user enters host http://testpage.com/current it rewrites it to another website hosted under port 5001. Sample config:

```
  <rule name="RewriteRule" stopProcessing="true">
                    <match url="^current(.*)?" />
                    <conditions logicalGrouping="MatchAll" trackAllCaptures="false" />
                    <action type="Rewrite" url="http://{HTTP_HOST}:5001/{R:1}" />
                </rule>
```

The site hosted under 5001 contains index.html and javascript file `index.js` which is referenced in `index.html` like this:

```
<script type="text/javascript" src="/index.js">
```

The entire configuration works super fine when I replace

```
    <match url="^current(.*)?" />
```

with

```
  <match url="^(.*)?" />
```

However when I use `current` here then it finds `index.html` located in page hosted under port 5001 but it can't find `index.js`. I suspect that the reason is because it tries to find `/current/index.js` but it doesn't exist.
I always thought that my `RewriteRule` should basically rewrite url to

```
http://testpage.com:5001
```

then get `index.html` and resolve `index.js` from current directory so it shouldn't have any knowledge about "current" resource.
Is there an easy way to fix this?
Obviously when I enter to the website like this:  `http://testpage.com:5001`, bypassing rewrite rules it works fine.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'll answer this for my future reference. It's not an issue with rewrite rules. The issue is with the way html resolves resources.
We need to do a few steps:

1. Set `<base href="virtualpath">`, in this example virtualpath should be equal to `/current`. We use webpack during TeamCity deployment to put correct value here. Example:

   `<script type="text/javascript">
       window.virtualpath = window.location.pathname.toLowerCase().indexOf("${virtual_path_legacy}") >= 0 ? "/${virtual_path_legacy}" : "";
       document.write("<base href='" + window.virtualpath + "/'/>");
   </script>`

   `new webpack.DefinePlugin({ "process.env": { NODE_ENV: JSON.stringify("production") }, virtual_path_legacy: JSON.stringify(virtual_path_legacy) })`
2. In `webpack.config.js` make sure your `publicPath` is "" instead of "/"
3. If you use `SignalR` make sure you pass your virtualpath to `$.hubConnection`(If SignalR is hosted under virtualpath)
   in .NET Core:

   `app.UseAppBuilder(appBuilder => appBuilder.MapSignalR(rootPath, hubConfiguration), camelCaseSerialization);`
4. If you use `react-router` make sure you pass virtualpath to `useRouterHistory`. Example:

   `const browserHistory = useRouterHistory(createHistory)({
     basename: infoService.virtualpath,
   });`
5. If you use libraries like `fetch` to connect to the API make sure to prefix all your api urls with virtualpath (if your API is also using virtualpath)